# Airflow create multiple instance of same task

Tags: python, airflow, scheduled-tasks

I'm so new with apache Airflow, my problem is when dag ran, multiple instance from same task created! However I expect one instance per each task

Here is code:

```
default_args = {
    "owner": "airflow",
    "depends_on_past": False,
    "start_date": datetime(2023, 7, 28),
    "email": ["airflow@airflow.com"],
    "email_on_failure": False,
    "email_on_retry": False,
    "retries": 1,
    "retry_delay": timedelta(minutes=5),
}




def run_building_pp_checks(province_id):
    query = f'''
       with building_section as(
       select id,population_point_id,province_id,county_id,zone_id,rural_id from building
       where province_id = {province_id} and deleted_at is null

       )


       select building.id from public.population_point pp
       join building_section building on building.population_point_id = pp.id and (pp.province_id != {province_id} or building.county_id != pp.county_id or  building.rural_id != pp.rural_id
        or building.zone_id != pp.zone_id ) 
       '''
    print(query)
    postgres_hook = PostgresHook(
            postgres_conn_id='my_postgres_conn',
         )
    result=postgres_hook.get_records(query)
    print(result)



    if result :
        values=[(id,'building',datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")) for id in result]
        print(values)
        postgres_hook.insert_rows(table='report.mismatch_records', rows=values , target_fields=['id' , 'table_name' , 'inserted_at'])



for province_id in range(1,39):
        task=PythonOperator(
            task_id=f'task_province_{province_id}',
            python_callable=run_building_pp_checks,
            dag=dag1,
            op_kwargs={'province_id': province_id},
        )

        if province_id!=1:
            task.set_upstream(previous_task)
        previous_task=task
```

in above code for each province one task create but when dag run multiple task for same task create! for example 5 instance create for province 1 and so on...

(the start_date is for 2 days ago from the time of running)

can any one help me to solve it?

Comment: as I set catchup=False ,it become ok but another problem is at run time 2 instance of dag create!!

Comment: Can you share the rest of the DAG code? What's the DAG's `schedule` (or `schedule_interval`) parameter set to?

Comment: @RNHTTR default_args = {
    "owner": "airflow",
    "depends_on_past": False,
    "start_date": datetime(2023, 7, 31),
    "email": ["airflow@airflow.com"],
    "email_on_failure": False,
    "email_on_retry": False} and also the interval set in dag defenition that i mentioned in post

Comment: Right, I'm interested in the dag definition, not the default args. I'd guess that `catchup` is not set to `False` and/or the `schedule` is brief, resulting in multiple DAG runs, which in turn results in "duplicate" task instances.